# OnSaveInstanceState call manually in android

Tags: android

I have a question. This is possible to call `onSavedInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` manually. I need that because I want to recreate all `Activity` but I want to save last all views. This is schema: I have in activity three toggle buttons, I check all buttons and click on button refresh. Now I want to recreate all views and save all states my buttons and other layouts. Something like `onConfigChange()` but without changing orientation.

Comment: if you change the language or the locale from the settings tab, and then from recent apps you call your activity then in that case, it would be recreated. May be you could think of a way of how to do it just the way it happens when locale is changed.

Comment: If only you want to refresh your activity, change the orientation to portrait and back to landscape, or whichever is applicable in your case. This should be the fastest way.